# Use a object in different controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, global-variables

This could be a silly question but I'm just confused.
I have a controller where a object is created & I want to use that object in several other controllers.
 Currently my object is a class variable, which gets overwritten when other user request or session request is made, I'm sure it is not good & will create some session problem.
Let's assume below is my scenario:

```
    @Controller
    public class DemoController
    {
        /* CURRENTLY THIS IS WHAT I'M DOING BUT I DON'T WANT THIS VARIABLE GLOBAL*/
        private MyCommonObject myCommonObject = new MyCommonObject();


        @RequestMapping(value="/demo-one", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView postControllerOne(@ModelAttribute SearchForm searchForm,
                ModelMap modelMap)
        {
            //I want to use this object in all other controllers too
            myCommonObject = someMethodToGetApiResult(searchForm);

            SomeOtherObject someOtherObject = getSomeObject(myCommonObject);
            modelMap.addAttribute("someOtherObject",someOtherObject);

            return new ModelAndView("/firstJSP");
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/demo-two", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView postControllerTwo(@ModelAttribute SomeForm someForm,
                ModelMap modelMap)
        {
            // Used the class variable here
            SomeOtherObject someOtherObject = getSomeObject(myCommonObject,someForm);

            modelMap.addAttribute("someOtherObject",someOtherObject);
            return new ModelAndView("/secondJSP");
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/demo-three", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView postControllerThree(@ModelAttribute SomeForm someForm,
                ModelMap modelMap)
        {
            // Used the class variable here
            SomeOtherObject someOtherObject = getSomeObject(myCommonObject,someForm);

            modelMap.addAttribute("someOtherObject",someOtherObject);
            return new ModelAndView("/thirdJSP");
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/demo-four", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView postControllerFour(@ModelAttribute SomeForm someForm,
                ModelMap modelMap)
        {
            // Used the class variable here
            SomeOtherObject someOtherObject = getSomeObject(myCommonObject,someForm);

            modelMap.addAttribute("someOtherObject",someOtherObject);
            return new ModelAndView("/fourthJSP");
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you fix your indentations to make the code human readable, I might actually look at the code.

Comment: @Andreas Did that. Wrote that code on stack's editor and not on some IDE so.. Well I'd be happy if get a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DemoController` is a *singleton*. There is only one instance *for all web requests*.

This means there is only one `myCommonObject` value in the entire webapp. Whoever hits `/demo-one` last wins, and all hits on `/demo-two` to `/demo-four` will use that last instance, regardless of who is doing it.

I assume `MyCommonObject` stores state information, otherwise why do what your trying to do. This state object is reset every time *anyone* hits `/demo-one`. Can't do that. In short, do not store state in a controller.

Since you want a `MyCommonObject` instance for each client, store it in the `HttpSession`.

Comment: Actually I'm building a flight booking web application. In the first controller I receive the response from the API of any search. I need that response object for the next 3 steps i.e pricing, reservation and ticketing. It's true that I can store the object in session (though the response object is too heavy), but what if a user logs in from 2 different systems? The last search persists in that case

Comment: Then you need to store the incomplete booking in a global Map, keyed by the user id. The Map can be in a static field, an instance field of a singleton (like your controller), or in a servlet application attribute. You may also consider storing them in the database, so they persist through restarts of the webapp server, and are shared if you cluster your (very popular) webapp. Appropriate logic for purging stale bookings would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a centralized server than declare a class as @Component and as a singleton, and initialize your object once.

If you are working in a distributed environment containing multiple servers, each server will have its own instance. In that case, you should use external server which will hold the class, and every other server will receive the value from that server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your `myCommonObject` in several `Controllers` and if this object holds state that is not specific to an user (i.e. scope is entire web application), then you may define it as a bean in your spring application context (XML or Java configuration and with scope singleton) and use it any `Controller` you want.